# Can we ask any question on any topic by tagging “Community Wiki” post?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

If yes, then here is my question:

> What is the global lock down's impact on the software industry for the long term? What will be the impact on technology trends?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: That sounds opinion based.

Comment: On which particular site did you plan to post that question?

Comment: [Quora accepts](https://www.quora.com/What-would-happen-if-a-wooden-ball-the-size-of-Texas-fell-into-the-ocean/answer/Dave-Consiglio) ([nearly](https://www.quora.com/What-would-happen-if-you-instantaneously-moved-Uranus-so-that-it-was-touching-Earth)) [any question](https://www.quora.com/What-would-happen-if-99-of-the-earths-crust-became-Uranium-235/answer/Dave-Consiglio). But you better make them comprehensible. Otherwise you are unlikely to get any answers.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, noone here claims to predict the future.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't. It will be closed and deleted, regardless of whether it's community wiki or not. What question you can ask are described in each site's [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), e.g.

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
- [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Your question isn't focused enough to be a good Stack Exchange question; I'd try Reddit or Quora.

---

<sub>P.S. I was rather confused by [this deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11747/295232) which states: "It's a category you can use to avoid having your question closed by (some) other users." Did it really use to be not possible to close those unless you were a ♦ moderator?</sub>

Comment: Nope, CW was never a superpower.

Comment: That answer was someone’s opinion, qualified with *(Or at least questions for which points should be awarded)*. Read all the way down to Shog9’s footnote on that post.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I stopped reading after the first paragraph ...